# Set a stylus variable based on the DOM parent

Tags: css, mixins, stylus

In stylus is it possible to change a variable based on the class of the parent?

I'm trying to create a variable which will change the colours from white to black depending on it being inside something with an '.inverted' class. I only want the variable to change though (so I can use it for any colour-based property).

If it were written in jQuery it would look like this:

```
$lightswitch = ($(this).parents('.inverse')) ? '#000' : '#fff';
```

I imagine there is a mixin or something I could write for this but I can't quite get my head around how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. I don't think that can be done with CSS or stylus. You'll have to use a jQuery solution for that.

Gotta wait for css4's "[parent selector](http://davidwalsh.name/css4-preview)!"  `$E > F`

Stay awesome!